# How do I center an embeded iTunes button?

Tags: button, alignment, center, itunes

I am trying to embed this iTunes button that I am putting on a site, but it seems to automatically alight left. Where and how in this code would I make the button center itself? Please see the example code below. Thanks!

```
<a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/believe-in-love-single/id993882452?app=itunes" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_itunes-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
```

Comment: do you have access to .css and html?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix if you have access to the css you could easily do this with flex box.

Wrap your anchor tag:

```
<div class="itunes">
    <a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/believe-in-love-single/id993882452?app=itunes" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_itunes-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
</div>
```

add this **css**:

```
.itunes {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;

}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ra65Lke/)

Although adding inline-styles is frowned upon..., if your in a pinch this will work as well. Please don't do this unless you must:

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
<a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/believe-in-love-single/id993882452?app=itunes" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_itunes-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;"></a>
</div>
```

---

note: flex box works on *most* browsers.